# Ассинхронный ajax-запрос + PHP. Зависание браузера

Tags: ajax, php

Привет, всем!

Ребят, кто в курсе. Делаю запрос посредством ajax, на стороне бекенда выполняется функция ftp_get, загружая в нужную директорию файл.

Как заставить браузер не зависать в процессе загрузки файла большого размера с ftp? Если открыть в браузере другую страницу этого же сайта, то она зависает, пока, по всей видимости, не выполнится запрос.

**UPD**. Я так понимаю это из-за блокировки сессии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю это из-за блокировки сессии?

Вы пробовали session_write_close?

Comment: Да, решил вопрос добавлением session_write_close.